# Moving objects released

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, fluid-statics, projectile, buoyancy

There is a balloon moving upwards with a small object attached to its bottom. If the object is released after some time, then will it start moving downwards suddenly, or will it move up a little with the balloon?

If yes, then how much distance will it cover and in what time?

Comment: At the point of release, the object is performing free-fall (accelerating downward with magnitude $g$). This, however, tells us nothing about the object's velocity. Indeed, if it is initially moving up with the balloon, then at the point of release the velocity will point upward and the acceleration downward. To quantify, SUVAT should suffice assuming no air-resistance.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the object is released it will start accelerating $g$ downward which means it will start decelerating upward with the same magnitude, $g$. The time duration and the distance covered can be calculated using following formulas,
$$t=u/g$$ where $u$ is upward speed at the time of object release.
$$s=ut-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$$
where t is calculated from the previous equation.